# accented chars form_validation codeigniter

Tags: php, regex, validation, codeigniter-2

how can i extend my existing form_validaion class to make it accept accented characters i'm using codeigniter and this is MY_Form_validation so far:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function alpha_dash($str){
        return (!preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9 _-])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }
}
```

by accented chars I mean this:

> > "é à è ç ê î â ô ï ö ë ä ù ..."

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the wanted characters in the class:

```
[a-z0-9 _àèéù-]
```

or use unicode properties:

```
[\pL\pN_ -]
```

`\pL` stands for any letter
`\pN` for any digit

**Exemple:**

```
$str = 'abcèéù';
echo preg_match('/^[\pL\pN_ -]+$/', $str) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

**output:**

```
TRUE
```

Comment: for the first one i want a generic solution i'm not going to write all the accented letters.

Comment: i think i have to write all the accented letter after all.

Comment: actually that worked after i copied your example i was using this `preg_match("/^([\pL\pN_ ])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;` after trying yours it did work thanks.

Comment: that only accepts accented chars right, because that what's happening now in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the accepted answer is incomplete.
The search pattern \pL is affected by the setLocale configuration. For it to work everywhere, you have to use unicode. Something like that:

```
public function alpha_dash($str){
    return (bool) preg_match('/^[0-9\pL _-]+$/u',$str);
}
```